Checking a date in EF Core in Azure Functions
I have a requirement that an Azure Function triggers every minute and checks (at that minute) a time 10 minutes before (so if it is triggered at 3:00pm -> it checks the database for rows which were sent to be the database at 2:50pm or earlier).
I cannot seem to get it right. Here is my code:
public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Timer triggered at {DateTime.Now}");
    log.LogInformation($"Checking transactions before / on {DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10)}");


    List<DebtCollectionList> debtCollections = 
        _context.Transactions
                .Where(x => x.Status == 0 
                            && x.TransactionDate <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
                .Select(x => new DebtCollectionList
                                 {
                                     transaction_id = x.TransactionId,
                                     iin_pan = x.IinPan,
                                     transaction_date = (DateTime)x.TransactionDate,
                                     amount = (decimal)x.Amount
                                 })
                .ToList();

I want the list to be populated with rows where TransactionDate is this moments minus 10 minutes as a minimum. So if it is 3pm then any rows from 2:50pm and earlier are populated. I am adding rows into the database and they are not being returned into the list I truly think it is something to do with
TransactionDate <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10)

Any advice would be amazing.

Is your database SQL Server? Have you used SQL Profiler to see what SQL is being executed?

So what is happening? Is there an error? No results? Wrong results? Why do you need to convert TransactionDate what type is it?

Wrong results :( ... I am wandering if i should just query the time.

Sample data, expected results, and what you are actually getting would help immensely.

I have it now working... I removed the
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);

and created this as a varialbe instead.
so like this and its now working :
var compareDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);

List<DebtCollectionList> debtCollections = _context.Transactions.Where(x => x.Status == 0  && x.TransactionDate <= compareDate).Select(x => new DebtCollectionList
{
    transaction_id = x.TransactionId,
    iin_pan = x.IinPan,
    transaction_date = (DateTime)x.TransactionDate,
    amount = (decimal)x.Amount
    


}).ToList();


I'm goign to hazard a guess that the current time on the server is different, probably a different timezone
